# Nearby connection Api When sending the file payloads it is very slow in the receiver side based on devices

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

If a connection strategy is P2P_CLUSTER, it's able to connect and send a payload to multiple devices, but it is very slow in receiving the payload from the sender.

In **Samsung s9, Samsung note9 and Lenovo PB2-670M devices** it is very slow.

In **LG g6, pixel 1, pixel 2 and moto 5s plus** it is fine when compared to the above-mentioned devices.

Please help me in figuring out the reason, why it is slow.

Comment: Anything found on this issue.